# MAMP phpMyAdmin error Access denied! MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Mamp can't connect with my phpMyAdmin. I allready changed password in config.inc but its still not working

[image]

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Check the credentials. The error is pretty clear.

Comment: It could also be a firewall issue, the port is closed.

Comment: I know its clear. I have set a password my host is on localhost and my username is also set. Yesterday I did not have this problem yet. I did not change anything so still have the same port.